# Java Finding Duplicates Using Array (Contains Concept)

Tags: java, list, for-loop, contains

I was trying on one of the questions on how to find a list of duplicated array. 
This program works:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CheckDuplicates {
public static void main(String[]args){

    boolean containsDuplicate;
    int[] values = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,3,4,5,10};

    List<Integer> myObj = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Set<Integer> dupInt = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for(int id : values){
        System.out.println(myObj);
        if(myObj.contains(id)){    
            System.out.println("From contains "+id);
            containsDuplicate = true;
            dupInt.add(id);
        }else{
            System.out.println("not contains "+id);
            myObj.add(id);
        }
    }

    for(int dup : dupInt)
        System.out.println(dup); // prints the duplicates
}
}
```

But I have a concept question on the for loop part. If

```
    List<Integer> myObj = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

creates an empty arraylist, then how does these lines work?

```
 for(int id : values){ if(myObj.contains(id)){ // Why is this true?
```

Although documentation says
contains

> boolean contains 
> (Object o) Returns true if this list contains the
>   specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this
>   list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null :
>   o.equals(e)). 
>  Specified by: contains in interface Collection 
>   Parameters: o - element whose presence in this list is to be tested 
>   Returns: true if this list contains the specified element

But I still don't understand the concept! Thanks in advance for explaining.

Comment: Well I did mention "how does these lines work?" and "// Why is this true?" I was pretty specific, maybe I should add that line before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the first check of myObj.contains(id) will always be false, but see the other part of your code:

```
else{
        System.out.println("not contains "+id);
        myObj.add(id);
    }
```

As the loop progresses, your list will be populated - and further iterations may satisfy that condition.